# Dynamic notification icon

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

In my android app, I'd like to show a notification where the icon is a circled number, the number depending on other factors that caused the notification. I've seen other apps do it but I'm unsure how to do it myself. I can create the icon I'm looking for in an activity, but I can't seem to create text in a drawable, and I don't know how I'd go about modifying it from the java side to create a dynamic drawable.

Any help would be great :)

How I'm creating the shape in an activity:

**activity**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="MY NUMBER HERE"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />
```

**circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">


<padding android:left="8dp" android:top="8dp"
    android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp" />
<corners android:radius="200dp" />
<size android:height="25dp"
    android:width="25dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@android:color/tab_indicator_text" />
</shape>
```

Edit: Found this: [Android Notification Dynamic Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522808/android-notification-dynamic-icon?rq=1)

it seems to imply if I want to do this, I'll need to generate a drawable for each different number I want to do. Is there no other way?

Comment: "Is there no other way?" - Starting in API 23, you can pass an [`Icon`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html), which you could generate dynamically, in `setSmallIcon()`. Before that, though, you're pretty much stuck with creating them ahead of time, since you can't alter resources during runtime.